# Rails - redirect to different page in same path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my Rails project, I have two different pages that exist within the same path - one is an index of stores, the other is a store update page (though I don't use those exact names for them).  The problem that I am having is that I am trying to add dynamic links to the index page for each store to take a user to the associated update page, but I created the routes manually (rather than use :resources) and both pages are listed under the same path in my Rails routes summary.  How can I use the <%= link_to %> helper in this situation?

First off, here is the relevant routing information...

```
stores_study_sites_path GET /stores/study_sites(.:format) stores#study_sites
                        GET /stores/store_details/:id(.:format) stores#store_details
```

And from my routes file...

```
  get 'stores/study_sites' => 'stores#study_sites'
  get 'stores/store_details/:id' => 'stores#store_details'
```

The first route, 'study_sites' is an index page, 'store_details' is the update page.

The redirect is rendered as a partial on the study_sites page...

```
<% @store.each do |store| %>
  <ul>
    <li>
        <%= store.name %></br>
        <%= store.street %></br>
        <%= store.city %> <%= store.state %></br>
        <%= render "shared/store_details", :store => store %>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

And finally, the partial that I would like to use, but does not currently work...

```
<%= link_to "Build store profile", stores_study_sites_path(store.id) %>
```

The urls generated from this look like `http://localhost:3000/stores/study_sites.26` whereas I need them to be `http://localhost:3000/stores/store_details/26`

I've gone through this basic procedure for a number of other redirects with no problem, but I've created these custom urls/routes, and now I'm in a bit of a pickle.  In a situation like this, how do I specify which url in the path I want the link to route to?

As a follow-up question (keep in mind I'm really new to Rails), why is the store_details page falling under the stores_study_sites_path?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name your routes manually:

```
  get 'stores/study_sites' => 'stores#study_sites', as: "first_route"
  get 'stores/store_details/:id' => 'stores#store_details', as: "second_route"
```

Then use them:

```
<%= link_to "one", first_route_path %>
## this will generate http://localhost:3000/stores/study_sites

<%= link_to "two", second_route_path(5) %>
## this will generate http://localhost:3000/stores/store_details/5
```

Answer (score 3):

### Be RESTful

When starting out with Rails try to avoid falling off the band wagon - most real world problems can be solved with the standard CRUD routes and RESTful representations. When you start creating a bunch of custom routes just for different representations then the quality tends to dip sharply.

A better URL scheme would be:

```
/stores                    # index of stores
/stores/1                  # show a single store
/stores/1/details          # index of details of a store.
```

`/stores/1/details` is what you would call a nested resource. Its very clear from the URL that we are looking something which belongs to a store.

You can declare the routes with:

```
resources :stores, shallow: true do
  resources :details
end
```

You can then create a link to the details of a store with:

```
<%= link_to "Build store profile", store_details_path(@store) %>
```

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: Thank you, those are very good points. In this case, I felt that needed to create these additional routes because I had already generated all of the standard CRUD resources for stores, but needed these additional views for stores that had a specific classification - they had to have their own index and update views.  I didn't know about nested resources, though - I am going to investigate that more, thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You really should put this setup [within the context of your `controller`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) in the routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :stores do
   get :study_sites, on: :collection  #-> url.com/stores/study_sites
   get :store_details, on: :member    #-> url.com/stores/:id/store_details
end
```

... and then in the view:

```
<%= link_to "x", stores_store_sites_path %>
<%= link_to "y", stores_store_details_path(store.id) %>
```

Comment: Ah that is very cool - max made a good suggestion about using the nested routes, but that doesn't exactly work in my particular circumstance.  What you have written here is the way that I need to handle this.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks buddy; yes, max's answer is good - I just wanted to chime in with my own .02